# ViewModel entre Fragments y activity

Tags: android, studio

Buenas noches estoy armando en Android una app que tiene 3 fragments , en donde voy seleccionando datos en cada fragment para luego mostrar todo lo seleccionado y guardarlo en la base de datos.

Mi gran inconveniente lo tengo con el *ViewModel entre fragments y un activity.*

Logre que el viewmodel funcione entre fragments de las misma Activity pero no logro utilizar el mismo viewmodel para un Activity.

¿ Me ayudan?

```
public class PageViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<Pedido> mPedido = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void setPedido (Pedido p){
        mPedido.setValue(p);
    }

    public LiveData<Pedido> getPedido(){
        if (mPedido == null)
            mPedido = new MutableLiveData<Pedido>();
        return mPedido;
    }
}
```

**Aqui van los Fragments :**

```
public class Cliente_fragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayAdapter<Cliente> arrayAdapterCliente;
    private ListView listV_Clientes;
    private List<Cliente> listaClientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    private Persona personaSeleccionada;
    private PageViewModel pageViewModel;
    private Pedido pedidoTemporal;

    public Cliente_fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cliente, container, false);
    }

//**Inicializo el ViewModel y luego lo utilizo en PersonaSeleccionada() para guardar el cliente**
 pageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(PageViewModel.class); 

        personaSeleccionada = PersonaSeleccionado(listV_Clientes);

private Persona PersonaSeleccionado(ListView listV_Clientes) {
        listV_Clientes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                personaSeleccionada = (Cliente) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                getEt_Nombre.setText(personaSeleccionada.getNombre());
                getEt_Telefono.setText(personaSeleccionada.getTelefono());
                getEt_Email.setText(personaSeleccionada.getEmail());
                getEt_Ciudad.setText(personaSeleccionada.getLocalidad());
                pedidoTemporal = new Pedido((Cliente) personaSeleccionada); //armo un pedido temporal y le asigno el cliente nuevo,
// **ACA USO EL VIEWMODEL --->**  
             pageViewModel.setPedido(pedidoTemporal);    // "LE paso" al viewModel el pedido que quiero que conserve para el otro fragment
            }
        });
        return personaSeleccionada;
    }
```

**Si utilizo el siguiente codigo en los Fragments funciona de maravilla**

```
        pageViewModel.getPedido().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Pedido>() { //Observer de clientes seleccionados en el fragments uno.
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Pedido pedido) {
                tv_nombreCliente.setText("CLIENTE : "+ pedido.getCliente().getNombre());
            }
        });
```

**El inconveniente lo tengo cuando quiero usar el mismo VieWmodel en un activity distinto**

```
public class detalle_Producto extends AppCompatActivity {
    //
    TextView tvTitulo, tv_descripcion,tv_prueba;
    EditText etCantidad;
    FloatingActionButton agregarPedido;
    private ProductosViewModel productosViewmodel;
    private PageViewModel pageViewModel;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detalle_producto);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        tvTitulo = findViewById(R.id.tv_Ttuloppal);
        tv_descripcion =findViewById(R.id.tv_descripcion);
        etCantidad = findViewById(R.id.eT_Cantidad);

        //Mediante un "tag" Consigo el producto seleccionado en el adapter para luego conseguir el titulo y descripcion ( o lo que necesite)
        Intent i = getIntent();
        final Producto prodSeleccionado = (Producto) i.getSerializableExtra("Producto");
        String Titulo = prodSeleccionado.getTela();
        String descripcion = prodSeleccionado.getBolsillo();

        tvTitulo.setText(Titulo);
        tv_descripcion.setText(descripcion);

//************************** **ACA BAJO** *******************************
        PageViewModel pageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PageViewModel.class);
        pageViewModel.getPedido().observe(this, new Observer<Pedido>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Pedido pedido) {
                tvTitulo.setText(pedido.getCliente().getNombre());
            }
        });
```

¿ Como hago para usar esa misma mutableLiveData en otro Activity ?
Cuando ejecuto el Observer que puse en el ultimo codigo , no obtengo nada porque claramente el PageViewModel es distinto al que uso en los fragments

Comment: Yo mi mutable live data las hago estaticas , asi cualquier objeto puede acceder y escuchar si aun un cambio.

Comment: No es una buena práctica hacerlos estaticos a los mutables, los mutables no deberian ser accesibles afuera del scope de donde se crean, solo hay que exponer LiveData

Comment: @Ubaldito , ViewModelProviders fue deprecado, te recomiendo actualizar la libreria y reemplazarlo por ViewModelProvider(this)

Comment: Coincido con @GastónSaillén , no me parece una buena practica, queria una solucion mas robusta.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar el patron one single activity, mediante el tiene tu actividad padre y los fragmentos que serian los hijos de la actividad, luego creas tu instancia de viewmodel en la actividad y compartes esa instancia con los fragmentos hijos y asi tendras el mismo viewmodel para la actividad y los 3 fragmentos.

Te dejo el ejemplo en kotlin:

- Primer paso: Instanciar viewmodel en la actividad:

```
private val authViewModel: AuthViewModel by viewModels()
```

Mi viewmodel:

```
class AuthViewModel() : ViewModel() {

}
```

- Segundo paso: Obtener la instancia del viewmodel de la actividad en el fragmento:

```
private val authViewModel: AuthViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

De esta manera solo creas una instancia de tu viewmodel y la mantienes en la actividad y todos los fragmentos que se encuentren dentro de esa actividad.